# In SSL handshake, does different cipher suite bit strength cause handshake failure?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, windows-server-2022

I have a .net client application (on Windows Server 2022) trying to connect to a web API on a server over https, and it's failing with a "handshake failure". I have compared available cipher suites on the two servers, and there are two matches found. However, they have differing bit strengths. Is the different bit strength possibly the cause of the handshake failure? If not, what other possible causes of the handshake failure could I investigate?

Here is the output in Wireshark:

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)
    Content Type: Alert (21)
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Length: 2
    Alert Message
        Level: Fatal (2)
        Description: Handshake Failure (40)
```

Client cipher suites:
[image: client cipher suites]

Server cipher suites:
[image: server cipher suites]

Edit: additional info based on comments
The supported names are as follows:

- Client: secp384r1, x25519, secp256r1
- Server: secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x25519

Comment: This is not about the bit strength of the cipher suite but about the curve used in the ECDHE key exchange.  Look for *Supported Named Groups* in the report and make sure there is an overlap between client and server.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich. I added the supported names to the question. There is overlap, but the order is different. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Order should not be a problem. So I suppose your problem is somewhere else. Handshake error can have a variety of reasons, for example a server expecting a client certificate but the client not sending one.